# Rails 5 collection_check_boxes for has_and_belongs_to_many not allowing individual selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with my `category` and `product` models.  The categories will display on the product form as checkboxes, but no matter what checkbox I select, it only effects the last checkbox on the list, so I am unable to select multiple categories.

**products/_form.html.erb**

```
...
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, checked: product.categories.map(&:id)) do |b| %>
    <%= b.check_box %> <%= b.label %>
<% end %>
...
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(
      ...
      category_ids: []
  )
end
```

**rendered html - from console**
There are two inputs that have the "checked" value.  This is because I started with a select option then switched to checkboxes.  I am unable to un-select the first checkbox. If I check it, it un-checks the last on the list.

```
<div class="input-checkbox">
  <input type="hidden" name="product[category_ids][]" value="">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="product[category_ids][]" id="product_category_ids_1">
  <label for="product_category_ids_3">Test One</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="product[category_ids][]" id="product_category_ids_2">
  <label for="product_category_ids_3">Test Two</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" checked="checked" name="product[category_ids][]" id="product_category_ids_3">
  <label for="product_category_ids_3">Test Three</label>
</div>
```

**Updated working code for multiple select_tag**
I needed to get the form working, so I went to multiple select options.  here is working code for Rails5. I would still like to get checkboxes working through.

```
<div class="cat-select">
  <% array = Category.all.map { |category| [category.name, category.id] } %>
  <%= select_tag 'product[category_ids][]', options_for_select(array, selected: @product.category_ids), multiple: true %>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you don't supply the `checked` option? Can the form magically update that without you passing it in?

Comment: @TarynEast Thank you for the reply.  Like mentioned, when I first setup the form, I used the select_tag and it worked, but I really wanted checkboxes. But when I switched the code, the items were already selected, which is why the `checked` options were already there.  Not sure if this is what you were referring to.  I would love to figure out the checkboxes. I updated my post with working code for the select_tag in the event someone finds this post and could use the code.

Comment: What I meant was: removed the `checked:` section from your checkboxes and see if it all just magically works... The reason I suggest this is that you are overriding the usual way that `form ... do |f|` works if you are deliberately passing in a set of `checked:` options... these might be interfering with one another and making weird things happen... it might also not be your problem... but it's worth checking :)